# How to know the number of time series counts in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am still new to IoTDB and am currently inserting my data into it from the old database. However I am not sure how many time series are there now. Want to know how to query the total number of time series amount under the database of Apache IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a column of time series that is not empty (for example, call that c1). Then, try to execute `select count(c1) from root.db.** group by level=1` in Apache IoTDB. See if this gives you the time series amount.